# Integer and referencing on python list slicing

Tags: python, list, reference

Could anybody explain the following list reference issue? I haven't understood it clearly .

For example :

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> a[0:2] = 11,22
>>> a
[11, 22, 3, 4]
>>> b = a[0:2]
>>> b[0:2] = 33,44
>>> b
[33, 44]
>>> a
[11, 22, 3, 4]
```

Why does `a[0:2] = 11,22` changes the list `a` but `b[0:2] = 33,44` doesn't? Isn't `b` referencing  `a[0:2]`? Why list's reference is changing its value, but integer's reference it won't?

Example:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = a
>>> a = 2
>>> b
1
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it is self-explanatory.

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]  
>>> a[0:2] = 11,22  
>>> a  
[11, 22, 3, 4]
```

You are modifying the value at the indices `0` and `1` of a. So, original values at indices `2` and `3` remain unchanged.

```
>>> b = a[0:2]  
>>> b[0:2] = 33,44  
>>> b  
[33, 44]  
>>> a  
[11, 22, 3, 4]
```

You have copied the values at indices `0` and `1` from `a` to `b` and hence `b` has only 2 values. Then you are overwriting the values of `b` with `[33,44]`. Hence the results what you observe.

There are certain data types which are immutable (values cannot be changed) such as numbers, strings, tuple. Data types like dict, list are mutable (values can be changed)

**Illustration**

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> b = a
>>> id(a)
46734952
>>> id(b)
46734952  

>>> b[1] = 8
>>> print(b)
[1, 8, 3, 4]
>>> print(a)
[1, 8, 3, 4]
```

In the above case, `b` is a reference to `a`. ie, Both `a` and `b` is pointing to the same list. Any change made to `b` will affect `a` also.  This can be verified by using the `id` function. Same `id` value says that both point to the same object.

```
>>> c = a[:]
>>> print(c)
[1, 8, 3, 4]
>>> id(a)
46734952
>>> id(c)
46563240
```

In the above case, slice of `a` is assigned to `c`. Hence a copy is made and assigned to `c`. Hence the `id` value of `a` and `c` are different.

Comment: b = a[0:2] .. i thought b references to a[0:2]...look like this:
    >>> a = [1,2,3]
    >>> b = a
    >>> b[0] = 10
    >>> b
    [10, 2, 3]
    >>> a
    [10, 2, 3]
so when the list is references? when the list is copied.. thanks :)

Comment: Edited my answer to give more info.

Comment: "I think it is self-explanatory", then goes on to give the explanation the OP needed... :)

Comment: @NedBatchelder Initially what I understood to be what the OP was asking was different and hence the first statement. Then I realized that he was asking something else than what I thought and hence gave the explanation.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Because there are two types of data

1. mutable data types

   - list
   - dict
   - set
   - classes
2. immutable data types

   - numbers (boolean, integer, float and complex numbers)
   - string
   - tuple
   - frozenset

When you change `mutable type` you change it object and when you change `immutable type` you create new object and then assign it to variable

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer step by step:

```
a[0:2] = 11,22
```

Is the same as doing `a[0] = 11; a[1] = 22`. That's regular assignment, no surprises here.
When you do:

```
b = a[0:2]
```

You get a *shallow copy* of the list. This means that you get a new list, with a reference to each object. Since in your case the list is filled with `int`s, it's essentially a copy as well. But consider this example:

Let's define a class, which wraps an `int` (or any other data type, it's python :) ), but is mutable.

```
In [41]: class num(object):
    ...:     def __init__(self, x):
    ...:         self.x = x
    ...:
```

Now we'll define `a` as before, only with our class

```
In [42]: a = [num(x) for x in range(1,5)]

In [43]: a[0].x
Out[43]: 1

In [44]: a[1].x
Out[44]: 2
```

Now, we'll assign a slice of `a` into `b`. Contrary to your example, when the list held the values of the numbers, here it hold the reference, so you could say they are the same:

```
In [45]: b = a[0:2]

In [46]: b[0].x
Out[46]: 1

In [47]: b[1].x
Out[47]: 2
```

So when I change one in `b`:

```
In [48]: b[0].x = 3
```

It's reflected in `a`:

```
In [50]: a[0].x
Out[50]: 3
```

But it's a different list. So assigning a new instance to a place in the list...

```
In [49]: b[1] = num(20)
```

... is not reflected in `a`:

```
In [51]: a[1].x
Out[51]: 2
```

Comment: oh. thank you so much ! so clear :). i understood it !

Comment: so if i have a assignment: a = 1, or a = 3 or blablalba.... this is just the reference of a to 1, or 3 is defined before in memory(i dont know how to call this exactly), right :) ? this look like the pointer in C ?

Comment: @TâmQuangVũ When you have an assignment, `a=1`, `a` holds the *value* of 1. When you do `a = num(1)` - `a` holds the reference to the `num` instance.